# Javascript - guessing game

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a mini number guessing game.
I wanted to know if it's possible to limit the number of times that the user can try guessing. 
Thanks!

```
<body>
    Pick up number: &nbsp;<input style="width: 40px" id="numberInput" type="number"> 
    <button onclick="takeMynumber()">Go</button> <br/>
    <p id="textOutput"></p>
    <script>
    var min = 0;
    var max = 10;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
        function takeMynumber(){
        var myRandom = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberInput").value);
        if (myRandom == random){
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Good Job!";
        }
        if (myRandom < random){   
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Greater than:  " + myRandom;      
        }
        if (myRandom > random){
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Less than:  " + myRandom;   
       }
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should accept the answer so that the question appears closed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another variable e.g. `tryCount` and increment it during each call to `takeMynumber` and check it therein.

```
<script>
    var min = 0;
    var max = 10;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
    document.write(random);
    var tryCount = 0;
    function takeMynumber() {
        ++tryCount;
        if (tryCount > 5) {
            alert("You already used your 5 tries");
            return;
        }
        var myRandom = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberInput").value);
        if (myRandom == random){
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Good Job <br/> Now try guess number between 0-100";
        }
        if (myRandom < random){   
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Greater than:  " + myRandom;      
        }
        if (myRandom > random){
        document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = "Less than:  " + myRandom;   
       }
    }
</script>
```

But really, you should read some basic tutorial about JS as you usually won't get any help for this simple 'problems' which could be solved easily with a search engine and some minutes.

Answer (score -2):

Well, How it will be possible ?

1: Binary search
   2: Interpolation search
Enter your choice of the method: 1
Is it 5? (<, >, =)
<

## Is it 3?

Done.